# How to Set Design Time Sizes and Positions for a Control in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, binding, design-time

I'm wondering if there is a simple way to set the design time sizes and positions for a control in Silverlight.

For example, there is a `TextBlock` on the canvas which is the `LayoutRoot`.  I want to set the `TextBlock`'s design-time `Width`, `Height`, `Canvas.Left`, and `Canvas.Top`. (NOTE: the run-time `Width`, `Height`, `Canvas.Left`, and `Canvas.Top` will be bound with a dynamic property in XAML (not in code).

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the DesignHeight and DesignWidth properties. But as far as I can tell, the others are not possible.

To get the width and height, make sure the xmlns for the design properties is brought in

```
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
```

Then, you can use it like so.

```
<TextBox d:DesignWidth="250" d:DesignHeight="75" />
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Really? It only works in the top-level UserControl, not a regular control inside of the UserControl.

Comment: My apologies. I don't typically use design mode for anything. So, when I saw that the d:DesignHeight property existed for the child controls, I assumed it worked.